# I need to compare columns within a same dataframe and rank them

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe with 6 columns I need to compare each 3 columns  with other three columns another. The 6 columns are same data but values of first 3 are from one method and other three are other method. So I need to compare them for differences or variations.

```
Df.head()

  A    B    C  A-1  B-1  C-1
190  289  300  190  287  267
```

And my conditions  are,

```
conditions = [(combined_min['A'] == combined_min['A-1']) & (combined_min['B'] == combined_min['B-1'] & combined_min['C'] == combined_min['C-1']),
              (combined_min['A'] > combined_min['A-1']) & (combined_min['B'] > combined_min['B-1'] & combined_min['C'] > combined_min['C-1']),
              (combined_min['A'] < combined_min['A-1']) & (combined_min['B'] < combined_min['B-1'] & combined_min['C'] < combined_min['C-1'])]
```

And my choices are,

```
choices     = [ "same", 'kj_greater', 'mi_greater' ]
```

Then I tried,

```
combined_min['que'] = np.select(conditions,choices, default=np.nan)
```

But it is throwing error message,

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

In the end I need a dataframe like this,

```
  A    B    C  A-1  B-1  C-1         que
190  289  300  190  287  267  kj_greater
```

The if the columns A, B, and C, are higher then kj_greater otherwise mi_greater, if all 6 are same then same.

Comment: this is due to operator precedence. You should enclose each condition under a parenthesis .

Comment: With your above data, I think the result will be `combined_min['que'] == np.nan`, since `combined_min['A'] == combined_min['A-1'] == 190`. Maybe make `combined_min['A'] == 191` in your example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Edit

After a bit of digging/reflection, I realized that I was wrong: it turns out that `&` *is* a logical operator in Pandas. `&` implements pairwise logical and between `pd.Series` and `pd.DataFrame` objects. Unfortunately, `&` has different operator precedence than `and`, so you have to be careful with it (in this case, `&` has higher precedence than `==`, `>`, or `<`). The bug in the OP's code just comes down to a lack of parentheses in the right places.

So to get the kind of labeling that the OP was originally after, the code would be:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

data= [
    [191, 289, 300, 190, 287, 267],
    [191, 289, 300, 200, 312, 400],
    [191, 289, 300, 191, 289, 300],
    [191, 289, 300, 200, 287, 400],
]
combined_min = pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns=['A', 'B','C','A-1','B-1','C-1'])

cond = lambda x: [(x['A'] == x['A-1']) & (x['B'] == x['B-1']) & (x['C'] == x['C-1']),
                  (x['A'] > x['A-1'])  & (x['B'] > x['B-1'])  & (x['C'] > x['C-1']),
                  (x['A'] < x['A-1'])  & (x['B'] < x['B-1'])  & (x['C'] < x['C-1'])]
choices = ['same', 'kj_greater', 'mi_greater']

combined_min['que'] = np.select(cond(combined_min), choices, default=np.nan)
print(combined_min)
```

This outputs:

```
     A    B    C  A-1  B-1  C-1         que
0  191  289  300  190  287  267  kj_greater
1  191  289  300  200  312  400  mi_greater
2  191  289  300  191  289  300        same
3  191  289  300  200  287  400         nan
```

Optionally, `cond` can be boiled down to a one-liner:

```
from functools import reduce
from operator import eq, gt, lt, and_

cond = lambda x: [reduce(and_, (op(x[c], x['{}-1'.format(c)]) for c in 'ABC')) for op in (eq, gt, lt)]
```

Though this reduces readability somewhat.

Comment: Thanks , it is printing NAH for all rows

Comment: @user1017373 I realized that I was wrong about `&` not being a logical operator, at least for Pandas objects. I posted a corrected answer with code that should label each row according to your original intention.

Comment: Thanks with this new editing it complains TypeError: object of type 'function' has no len()

Comment: @user1017373 I think I know what might be causing that `TypeError`. Is there a line in your code that looks like: `np.select(cond, choices, default=np.nan)`? You can't pass the `cond` lambda directly to `np.select`, you have to call it and pass the result. The line should instead look like `np.select(cond(combined_min), choices, default=np.nan)`. If you're having trouble, first try just copy/pasting the code from my answer and see if you can get that to run as is.

Answer (score 1):

You're error is in your conditions. The problem is that you are not directly comparing booleans, but rather a set of pd.Series containing a boolean, which connot be directly compared as you do.

So:

```
df['A'] == df['A-1']
```

Returns:

```
0    True
dtype: bool
```

So when you do:

```
df['A'] == df['A-1'] & df['A'] == df['A-1']
```

You get the error you mentioned. Try separating each term using parenthesis, and using `any()` to get the boolean from the pd.Series:

```
((df['A'] == df['A-1']) & (df['A'] == df['A-1'])).any()
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are missing parenthesis on conditions. Each conditions has to be surrounded by parenthesis.

```
conditions = [(combined_min['A'] == combined_min['A-1']) & (combined_min['B'] == combined_min['B-1']) & (combined_min['C'] == combined_min['C-1']),
          (combined_min['A'] > combined_min['A-1']) & (combined_min['B'] > combined_min['B-1']) & (combined_min['C'] > combined_min['C-1']),
          (combined_min['A'] < combined_min['A-1']) & (combined_min['B'] < combined_min['B-1']) & (combined_min['C'] < combined_min['C-1'])]
```